# Re-implement sorting for QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there a way to re-implement the sorting function for `QTableWidget`? I use `QComboBox` (multicheck) in the first row of my table to filter the data. I also want be able to sort the data in the table, but I want my widget to stay in the first row no matter how I sort the data.

I know that I can re-implement the < operator and set a value as well as a widget in a cell, but that does of course not help me.

Comment: You are looking for a "frozen row". There is one fine example for column, I belive you should be able to figure it out for a row: http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/itemviews-frozencolumn.html